Veracrypt - Encrypt spare C boot drives for same computer but using a USB caddie instead
I have 2 spare boot drives for same computer. i want to fully encrypt them using a usb caddie but as it is a "system encryption", it requires that test stage with "boot" and you put in password and it goes through then does the full encryption. WILL it allow me to do it this way through the caddie , or does every boot drive need to be the ONLY C drive that the computer is actually running right then, so i would need to plug each of them in as C drive with only one c drive with no caddie? I want to keep working with current up to date fast C drive while i encrypt the other 2 spare Boot drives through the Caddie.
The other option would be to clone to the caddie from current encrypted C drive to spare drives but would the "bit by bit copy" include the special Verycrypt boot leader ect from the c drive to those drives? Anyone who knows Veracrypt and knows the actual solution would appreciate your reply.
Why encrypt ALL your drives? No brainer. Break ins, they steal your computer and all your data, passwords, bank details ect . Veracrypt deincrypts all your data you request through RAM and no unencrypted data is put back on your HD. So its totally safe and just needs a Password at each boot using its own special boot loader.
thanks

What purpose does the paragraph beginning with "Why encrypt ALL your drives?" serve in this question? I think your question makes more sense without that paragraph. When a drive is not mounted as the main drive, it will not be "C" or "boot", especially when it is connected externally, as a removable drive. It isn't clear what the purpose of these "spare boot drives" are. Is this a quick recovery mechanism, or a backup, or something else? Maybe you should rethink your recovery or backup strategy to work within the limits of the technology you have?
